# python datetime add seconds from now

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to do is add `3` seconds to `now()`

```
def now(dt): 
    import datetime
    ts = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(seconds=dt)
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return st
```

gives me `st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') TypeError: a float is required`

So I `float(ts)`

```
def now(dt): 
    import datetime
    ts = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(seconds=dt)
    st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return st
```

Traceback:

`st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(ts)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Comment: You already *have* a `datetime` object, why try and treat it as a timestamp (floating point value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ts` is a [datetime.datetime object](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects). Such objects have a `strftime` method, so you do not need to call `fromtimestamp`.

```
import datetime as DT
def now(dt): 
    import datetime
    ts = DT.datetime.now()+DT.timedelta(seconds=dt)
    st = ts.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return st
```

The first error you were seeing is due to the fact that `fromtimestamp` expects a float as input. `ts` is not a float.

The second error is due to `float` expecting a string or number. `ts` is neither a string nor a number.

Comment: the datetime object is really confusing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's confusing about it? Is there something we can do to clarify?

Comment: `return format(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` is also an option